# google sheet unexplained format on a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am collecting some info for 2020 taxes, and am not sure what I did. One single cell is framed in green. When I hover over it, it shows my name. How can I fix this please, (remove it)?

Comment: If you provide a public link to the spreadsheet we can tell you. You can always make a copy of just the problem cell and share that as a standalone spreadsheet. Because right now you are saying, I am looking at something tell me what I am looking at, and I can only do that if I can see what you see.

Comment: A screen shot wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the file open in another browser tab. So when you are looking at one it shows the user (you) is possitioned in that cell

Comment: That you see, if I guessed correctly, is what you'd always see when another user opens the same file. It shows the cell the other users have selected as people can edit the file at the same time. When you open the file in 2 or more tabs you will see your other instances as other users with your name

Comment: Based on the limited info in the original question, this sounds like the right answer.